# python regex replace <ul...> and <li...> tags with <ul> and <li>, resp

Tags: python, regex, html-lists

Hi I want to remove all attributes from `<ul>` and `<li>` tags using python regex. Below is my source string:

```
peanut butter1
<ul id="ul0002" list-style="none">peanut butter2
    <li id="ul0002-0001" num="0000">2.0 to 6.0 mg of 17&#x3b2;-estradiol and</li>
    <li id="ul0002-0002" num="0000">0.020 mg of ethinylestradiol;</li>
    <li id="ul0002-0003" num="0000">0.25 to 0.30 mg of drospirenone and</li>
    <li id="ul0002-0004" num="0000">0.1 to 0.2 mg of cyproterone acetate,</li>peanut butter3
</ul>
```

What I want to output:

```
peanut butter1
<ul>peanut butter2
    <li>2.0 to 6.0 mg of 17&#x3b2;-estradiol and</li>
    <li>0.020 mg of ethinylestradiol;</li>
    <li>0.25 to 0.30 mg of drospirenone and</li>
    <li>0.1 to 0.2 mg of cyproterone acetate,</li>peanut butter3
</ul>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import re
for line in open('sample.html'):
    print re.sub('<(ul|li)[^>]*>', r'<\1>', line, flags=re.I),
```

The above will remove attributes from all ul and li tags whether there is one or several tags on a line.  Also, because `re.I` is used, the search is case-insensitive and tags such as `<UL...` will be found and their attributes removed.  Text outside of tags is left unchanged.

With your (revised) sample html, the above code produces:

```
peanut butter1
<ul>peanut butter2
    <li>2.0 to 6.0 mg of 17&#x3b2;-estradiol and</li>
    <li>0.020 mg of ethinylestradiol;</li>
    <li>0.25 to 0.30 mg of drospirenone and</li>
    <li>0.1 to 0.2 mg of cyproterone acetate,</li>peanut butter3
</ul>
```

#### Processing the whole file at once

If the data is not too long, it can be processed all at once instead of one line at a time:

```
import re
string = open('sample.html').read()
string = re.sub('<(ul|li)[^>]*>', r'<\1>', string, flags=re.I)
print string
```

Comment: John, great answer. Will this work in the edited situation above where I have text outside the li or ul elements? If not please update your answer, thanks.

Comment: @user2104778 Yes, it works on the revised sample.  Text outside of tags is left unchanged.

Comment: It doesn't work unless you switch "for line in open('sample.html'):" with "for line in open('sample.html').split("\n"):"

Comment: @user2104778 Would you check that again? It works fine for me as is.  Using `open('sample.html').split("\n")` will, however, result in `AttributeError: 'file' object has no attribute 'split'`.

Comment: I think maybe the reason we get different results is because I feed a string in instead of open('sample.html').

Comment: @user2104778 Yes, that explains the difference completely.

Comment: John I get odd odd results if I try and add the re.sub output to a string, say by going 'str1 = str1 + re.sub('<(ul|li)[^>]*>', r'<\1>', line, re.I)'. The string doesn't add the data properly. If I add to an list, the data adds fine, but I get the same oddity if I then join the  list into a string.

Comment: Also, how do I make the re.sub replaceall, so I can just run it once on the entire string?

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
    >>> xs='<li id="ul0002-0001" num="0000">2.0 to 6.0 mg of 17&#x3b2;-estradiol and</li>'
    >>> p=r'(<li|<ul|</ul)[^>]*(>)(.*)'
    >>> match=re.search(p,xs)
    >>> ''.join([match.group(1),match.group(2),match.group(3)])
        '<li>2.0 to 6.0 mg of 17&#x3b2;-estradiol and</li>'
    >>> xs='<ul id="ul0002" list-style="none">'
    >>> match=re.search(p,xs)
    >>> ''.join([match.group(1),match.group(2),match.group(3)])
        '<ul>'
```